# NPM Error: Must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript

Tags: javascript, npm

Very, VERY new to coding, been following this tutorial to get a bot online in Discord so I can begin to puzzle through the actual coding part of the bot. This part SHOULD be the easiest, but I've spent over 6 hours on this problem.. I've tried updating Java, updating computer drivers, restarting afterward, verifying the code across other tutorials, changing the versions of notepad that open the file types, running npm clear cache and it's STILL not working.

```
{
  “
  name”: “Marvel - Mayhem”,
  “version”: “1.0 .0”,
  “description”: “A Marvel trading card game”,
  “main”: “bot.js”,
  “author”: “White Crow”,
  “dependencies”: {}
}
```

When running clear cache it asks me if I'm super sure, and to type force if I am, and when I do, it has a warning that quotes 'I hope you know what you're doing'. I'm not sure if that's it running the cache clear? or if there's one more thing I need to type in to continue? ANY help would be so appreciated.

Comment: I think you're confused.  Java != Javascript: https://www.thesoftwareguild.com/faq/difference-between-java-and-javascript.  Q: Are you trying to write a [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/) app (i.e. Javascript)?  Q: Are you getting the error "Must be actual JSON, not just Javascript" when you try to run the "npm" command?  Q: *COULD YOU PLEASE UPDATE YOUR POST WITH THE EXACT COMMAND THAT'S GIVING THE ERROR?*

Comment: I very probably am, I'm really, REALLY a novice here. But I just don't see why this tutorial wouldn't be working. I found this same tutorial in 2 different sources. I followed to the letter, but it's just pulling that error. I'll change the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have "funny quotes" in your data.  JSON requires that only standard double quotes appear in an encoding to be valid.  If you replace the non-standard quotes with regular standard quotes, then the data structure you give in your question will be readable by any standard JSON decoder.

This is a mistake that's easy to make.  When you copy and paste something from the web, you sometimes get these strange kinds of quotes.  I've always thought that was really lame.  It's also possible that your editor is adding them later on.  There may be a setting or a command in your editor that will replace the funny quotes with standard double quotes.

I hope this solves your problem.  I can't be sure because you never really state what your problem is exactly.

Comment: Ohhhhh! Now I got you! I bet you're right! I'll test it out and close the question! Thank you so, so much!

Comment: @White Crow: "you never really state what your problem is exactly".  Specifically, you should tell us exactly what command you typed or line of code you executed that caused the error.  Please update ("Edit") your post: 1) Copy/paste the EXACT error message.  2) Copy/paste the command that resulted in the error.